# Vuetify 3, vite, pnpm, monorepo - [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import *.css

Tags: vuejs3, vite, pnpm, vuetifyjs3, pnpm-workspace

I have a monorepo setup using pnpm. All packages are TS except front-end one that is a Vue 3, Vuetify 3, vite project. Originally it was Vue 2, Vuetify 2, and web pack.

When I finished my migration and it was able to compile I start to receive a lot of erros like:

```
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "/Users/**/Documents/GitHub/lorehub-front/node_modules/.pnpm/vuetify@3.1.4_24g3gyrmoyehrpsuzyze56xdda/node_modules/vuetify/lib/directives/ripple/VRipple.css"
```

My project folders:

```
- packages
- - package1 (ts)
- - package2 (ts)
- - front (vue3, vuetify3, vite)
- package.json
- and pnpm related files
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem was how Vite was trying to resolve dependencies.

So I add .npmrc file to the root folder.

```
- packages
- - package1 (ts)
- - package2 (ts)
- - front (vue3, vuetify3, vite)
- package.json
- and pnpm related files
- .npmrc
```

With this content:

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*vuetify*
```